# How can I capitalize one variable and save it as a new variable in sass/scss?

Tags: sass

My scss file provides an area where users can change certain variables. For example:

`$variant-color-multi: "multicolor";`

I would like this variable to be capitalized and saved to a new variable. For example:

`$variant-color-multi-capitalized: "Multicolor";`

That way if the value of `$variant-color-multi` is changed to "bunt" for example, then `$variant-color-multi-capitalized` would automatically output "Bunt".

I tried using the string functions below to manipulate my original variable, but that wasn't working. I'm a newbie to sass.

```
$variant-color-multi-first:         slice($variant-color-multi, 1, 1);
$variant-color-multi-first-captial: to-upper-case($variant-color-multi-first);
$variant-color-multi-rest:          slice($variant-color-multi, 2, -1);
$variant-color-multi-capitalized:   $variant-color-multi-first-captial + $variant-color-multi-rest;
```

Comment: Is it what you are looking for? https://gist.github.com/pascalduez/10011785